# Yii2 filter related model

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a `Sale` model, that contains a `property_id` FK to `Property` model.

On Property model, there is a field `office_id`.

The Sale controller contains a partial _search view that I am using to try filter via the office_id.

In search function, I first set the relations to find():

```
$query = sale::find()->with([
        'property',
        'listerSaleStaff',
        'listerSaleStaff.staff',
        'sellerSaleStaff',
        'sellerSaleStaff.staff',
    ]);
```

The filter clause:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'property.office_id', $params['SaleSearch']['office']]);
```

where `$params['SaleSearch']['office']` does in fact contain the correct office_id

I'm getting PDOException:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'property.office_id' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sale` WHERE ((`settle_date` >= '2016-07-03') AND (`settle_date` <= '2016-07-31')) AND (`property`.`office_id` = '5')
Error Info: Array
(
[0] => 42S22
[1] => 1054
[2] => Unknown column 'property.office_id' in 'where clause'
```

Property model does contain relationship:

```
public function getOffice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Office::className(), ['office_id' => 'office_id']);
}
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set the join for search

```
$query->joinWith(['office' => function ($q) use ($params['SaleSearch']['office']]) {
            $q->andFilterWhere(['=', 'property.office_id', $params['SaleSearch']['office']]);
        }]);
```

Comment: i think that will work, but how do i get to $params inside that closure function ? Its giving undefined variable in there ?

Comment: For passing  the param inside the anonymous function  you can use  ... "use"  ... i have update the answer ..